# node.js extension: Is it possible to set Handle<Value>'s without ::New

Tags: c++, node.js, memory

I'm writing a node.js extension that has a processing thread, and I need to be able to set some values and then call a javascript callback within the processing loop.

When I call String::New or Number::New while processing, it causes allocation, which crashes the application. Is it possible to set the value of a Handle without using something like Number::New and causing allocation?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but a similar problem that might help lead to an answer from someone else.  

Normally, you need to use `Locker myLocker;` before entering the HandleScope if you expect to call JS from multiple C++ threads.  Otherwise v8 WILL crash.  This works very well in embedded v8 applications -- it has not worked for me with Node.js.  Evidently, some other process inside Node's implementation is holding the lock.  I can call native code from the main JS all day long, but the moment I need to call JS from  my own thread, it blocks forever (and `Locker::IsActive()` returns true).

Comment: @jdo thanks for the response. I've managed to get things working using a hack. On my processing thread, I set status flags and hold onto a 'main thread copy' of the data. Then, I create a timer that runs on the main thread, and constantly polls the processing thread for status changes. This is obviously inefficient, but it works :/